# Visited tags are styled differently to unvisited ones

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, design

I just recently noticed that the font color inside the tags behaves like links, which means the font color is the normal dark grey/light black when the corresponding link (i.e. the respective tag page) has not been visited yet. But once you click/visit that tag, it turns into a dark cyan blue font. This happens on the main site and on meta and seems to be a very recent "feature".

[image]
[image]

Now first of all, I'd like to know **if this is a feature at all or just a bug** somehwere in the style sheet or whatever. Or maybe this just happens to me (on Firefox 37.0.2).

If it is actually supposed to be a feature, though, then **I would question its validity**, since it doesn't seem to be relevant if one has ever visited a tag's page and it just results in an inconsistent design for tags which suggests a semantic difference between the tags where there is none. It also seems to rob the tags of the nice contrast their rather greyish color made to the rest of the very cyan-heavy font colors of a questions list.

**UPDATE:** The same bug/feature seems to apply to those little light grey *"modified/answered/asked X hours ago"* thingies under the question title in the questions list, too. And as it is for tags, this different coloring is equally unnecessary and distracting there, too.

Comment: This does not seem to be standard on any of the other SE sites I visit. I'm guessing it's a bug.... or maybe not, it's like that on Cooking.SE, too, now that I look closely.

Comment: Appear a weird feature to me, i didn't noticed it before.

Comment: Ok, since noone seems to care about this, I finally [went up a hierarchy level](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257431/162011).

Comment: Hopefully they won't yell at you. Good thing I found the SA thing, though.

Comment: @Catija Well, if you answer right away *before* it gets annoying, you don't have to yell *when* it gets annoying. ;-)

Comment: The CSS A:Visited selector allows for marking a visited link separately from a un-visited link. Its useful!

Comment: @cde But not in this case. What does it use to know you've once visited a tag? It seems much more distracting that way.

Comment: See http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/50729

Comment: @cde Well, then tell that to [meta.se]. As long as we're the only site doing that, it's clearly a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pushed a fix earlier today. Should be good now.

Comment: Way to kill visited link css color differentiation. Now I can't tell which tags I've visited anymore :(

Comment: @cde And why would you?